# How do i make a sql select dynamic string comparison to work?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, string-comparison

I´m trying to get the correct string from a wpf datagrid clicked cell that i will use in a sql select statement to a second wpf datagrid.
When entering a static string value it will work, but not from a dynamic string. What is wrong with my code?

```
    private void dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItems[0];
        string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString();

        //string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "'";
        string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = 'L002BO4'";
    }
```

When entering the string in the sql statement it works like a charm, but ofcourse i want the dynamic string returned from the large database work as well.

Comment: I forget to mention that
string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString(); returns L002BO4, just like i want it.

Comment: what sorta dynamic string you are looking for from database is the query as comment up and running or that is the dynamisation sending input as variable meaning not manually entering are you referring to

Comment: Are you getting the barcode_string as you expected value while debugging

Comment: I forget to mention that string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString(); returns L002BO4, just like i want it.

string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "'";
Doesn´t work.

Comment: did you see the output on printing the same statement ?

Comment: Just print that query in the log itself syso("SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "'")

Comment: string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString(); returns L002BO4 (that is correct)

Comment: did the query had error or no output.Just print that query in the log itself syso("SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "'") If you can share this printed query it would help

Comment: Would you please provide me the correct syntax instead?
I don¨t know how to debug it in log as you said?
It´s something wrong with the syntax of BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "' i guess?

Comment: can you try with my answer once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not concatenate strings in SQL statements. Use parameters. Check your database for the correct data type of the BarCode column.

```
    private void DataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItems[0];
        string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString();

        //string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = '" + barcode_string + "'";
        string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = @BarCode;";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string")) 
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(barcode_detail, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BarCode", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = barcode_string;
            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            //use the data in the data table
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Test the strings. Add `using System.Diagnostics` to use `Debug.Print`

```
        String literal = "L002BO4";
        String variable = row["BarCode"].ToString();
        if (literal.Length == variable.Length)
            Debug.Print("The length of the strings match");
        else
            Debug.Print("The lengths do not match");
        Char[] variableArray = variable.ToCharArray();
        Char[] literalArray = literal.ToCharArray();
        for (int index =0; index<literalArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (variableArray[index] == literalArray[index])
                Debug.Print($"index {index} matches");
            else
                Debug.Print($"index {index} does not match");
        }
```

Comment: Don´t know what you are talking about. I want to make a string comparison. How hard can it be to make it right?
I´ve done this thousands of times before, but in this case it doesn¨t work. What IS wrong?

Comment: @MattiasSturebrand "Don´t know what you are talking about. " Well, that makes two of us.

Comment: I´ve isolated the error to the expression:
string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString();
It seems to return a string of L002BO4, but it is not like that you declare
string barcode_string = "L002BO4"
So what is wrong???

Comment: Try `.Trm` there may be invisible white space.

Comment: Would you please give me an example of that?
I guess you would make me using a trim expression of the string?

Comment: `string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString().Trim();`

Comment: Sorry... It doesn´t work.
I´m going slightly crazy here.
string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString() gives me a string of L002BO4 whithout whitespaces and so on....

Comment: But the expression
string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = " + barcode_string + "";
Doesn´t give me the right data. It gives me nothing - and no exceptions thrown.

Comment: Does `if  (barcode_string  = "L002BO4") {MessageBox.Show("True") }

Comment: DO NOT concatenate strings in an SQL Statement.

Comment: You want to say:

            if (barcode_string == "L002BO4")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("True");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not True");
            }

Comment: It says "Not true"

Comment: As i said before , the problem is in that expression.
Is string barcode_string = row["BarCode"].ToString() not giving me a string?
It seems so when presenting i n messagebox and in a textbox.

Comment: How can i convert a string into a string??

Comment: See Edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Mary.
It was wrong in string length, so i have corrected it now.
Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

You just missed one `"` at the last of your query. Try this

```
    string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID 
       FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE
          BarCode = "+"\'" +barcode_string + "\'";
```

Comment: No, i´m sorry, but that is not the correct syntax.
string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = "+"'" barcode_string + "'";

Comment: oops i missed `+` can you please check now

Comment: No, i´m sorry, but that is not working.

string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = "+"'" + barcode_string + "'";

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like below

```
 string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode = "+ barcode_string;
```

Comment: Can you try using like this --> string barcode_detail = "SELECT BarCode, PCBGUID FROM TB_AOIResult WHERE BarCode =  N''' barcode_string ''' ";